# Is there a way to change an entire columns value in a SharePoint list

Tags: javascript, list, sharepoint, boolean

I have a simple SharePoint list which consists of 2 columns, username and a Boolean Yes/No expression. It is used for users to acknowledge that they have read a document. I would like to create a button that would set all users Boolean expression back to ‘No’ when the document is amended/updated. Is there a way to do this?

I am very new to SharePoint and have not had a lot of experience with JavaScript. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not provide a way to confirm that the user whether has read the document.

As a workaround, you could add a workflow to update the list value ,Users can start the workflow after reading the document.

Comment: I understand that SharePoint doesn’t provide a way. My list was a way of the user to manually toggle the expression to ‘YES’ when they have read it, then when I change the document, I can manually change them all back to ‘NO’ on mass.   Workflows is not something I have played with yet but I will look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain two columns that you have added are part of the same document library , Or document & two columns in separate list.

If you have idea of JavaScript, then you can write CSOM Javascript code to implement the above scenario. you can also make use of SharePoint REST Calls.

If you have idea of C#, then you can write even receivers to clear off the boolean values based on Document State Changes.